# mod rewrite for pretty urls and also hide index.php

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can i mod-rewrite  to obtaining a pretty url like below

```
example.com
```

contains a form to get a text value and pass it another file for processing that file is in directory as web but i need to change that as pretty urls

```
example.com/web/index.php?url=mydomain.com
```

to

```
 example.com/web/mydomain.com

 example.com/web/newdomain.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+web/index\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /web/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^web/(.+?)/?$ /web/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I think i am not explained the problem clearly i put the above code but it still using as `exapmle.com/web/index.php?url=mydomain.com` i put it in `c:\wampp\www\example\    directory` is it correct destination

Comment: Its improved now it converts a `example.com/web/?url=mydomian.com` but i need its as `example.com/web/mydomian.com` please improve the answer

Comment: May be i am confusing, i need that `/web/index.php?url=mydomain.com` to `/web/mydomain.com` correct the code for this sir  both `index.php?url=` should be hided

Comment: I had a bad copy/paste. Above code externally redirects `/web/index.php?url=mydomain.com` to `/web/mydomain.com`

Comment: No sir, its not working that as i said earlier its rewrite only `/web/index.php?url=mydomain.com` to `/web/?url=mydomian.com` but when i try to access `/web/mydomain.com` it shows 404 error

Comment: i found the mistake its really the problem is adding backslash to the url . I got it wright only with below code `RewriteRule ^web/(.+?)/?$  web/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]` without the backslash. Thanks anubhava.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. Happy Diwali :)

Comment: Its makes me learn complete rewrite apache rules.Finally it worked. Happy Diwali @anubhava